# Trying to console.log an id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get the id from a div tag and to console.log it but i get undefined.
Any ideas why is that happened?

```
<?php $id = get_the_ID(); ?>
<div class="about-cont" id="<?php echo $id ?>"></div>

<script>
    jQuery('.about-cont').click(function(el){
         console.log(jQuery(el.target).attr('id')); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
<script>
    jQuery('.about-cont').click(function(){
         console.log(jQuery(this).attr('id')); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works..Thank you! Can you explain to me why the el.target doesn't work?

Comment: You have added click event on that div. So, you can access that attribute with jQuery(this). You not need to target the element.

Comment: Just to be clear, `el.target` should absolutely work too. If it doesn't, there's something else in you code that's not in your question (probably other HTML elements in the div?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event` argument to easily find the clicked target. Also, you can prevent all the events related to that action by using `event.preventDefault();` in the function block.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery('.about-cont').click(function(event){
         console.log(jQuery(event.currentTarget).attr('id')); 
         //or
         console.log(jQuery(event.target).attr('id')); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: I have added some explanation for my answer. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can Do like this, (this.id) is fetch current element id.

```
<?php $id = 1; ?>

<div class="about-cont" id="<?php echo $id ?>">click</div>

<script>
    jQuery('.about-cont').click(function(el){
         console.log(this.id); 
    });
</script>
```